# Can't push to git remote repositories

Tags: git, webdav

I'm having trouble pushing my code to a git remote repository from my localhost.  **This problem only appears for repositories that were initially created with remote urls that are system directories (eg. /var/www/lib) and later accessed via remote urls that are http urls (`eg. http://mysite.com/repo.git`)**.  Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/tags/
  refs/heads/
  fetch 023264fe3e5e24075307512502599d279c1a1640 for refs/heads/master
error: remote 'refs/heads/master' is not an ancestor of
local 'refs/heads/master'.
Maybe you are not up-to-date and need to pull first?
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Here are the steps to creating the problem.  Initially, I populated the remote bare repository from the remote server itself like so:

```
cd /var/www/
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'test'
git remote add newproject /var/lib/git/newproject.git  ## I suspect the problem begins here
git push newproject master
```

For about a week, I've been committing, pulling and pushing without problems because I was working directly off of the remote server from `/var/www/`.  Then today, I installed webdav so that I can push and pull from my local host.   I'm pretty sure I installed and configured git and apache properly.  So from my localhost, here's what I did:

```
cd /home/user/newproject/
git init
git remote add newproject http://www-data@website.com/newproject.git  # this is different from above where i used /var/lib/git/newproject
git pull newproject master   #worked perfectly
vi test.html
git add test.html
git commit -m 'test'
git push newproject master
```

Then I get the error as first mentioned.   A pull did not fix this problem.  All new repositories made with the http versions have no problem with push and pull.  Only old repositories that were first made with /var/lib/git are having problems when switching to the http version.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I take from your question, that webdav for the same user works as intended for other repositories, so webdav is configured correctly.

Where does `http://www-data@website.com/newproject.git` point to?
Does it point to the repo at `/var/lib/git/newproject.git` or to `/var/www`?

I can see two potential problems:

1. The httpd user needs **write access** to all repo files
2. The repository should be **bare**

#### Write access for the httpd user

Does the webserver have write access to all parts of the repository?
When you pushed locally, you might have created files with a user account (or root) that the webserver can't write now.
Obviously the same applies when the webserver tries to access the repo at `/var/www`.

The best option would be to `chown -R` all files to the httpd user.

#### Bare repo

Is the destination repo a bare repo?

It is technically not necessary for the repo to be bare,
but there are issues that can arise when you have a checked out working copy of a branch you are pushing to.
Your problem might be one of these issues.

See also [how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare)
and [all about "bare" repos](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html).

You should check `git status`, `git branch` and similar in the destination directory for problems.

---

If you keep having issues, another obvious option is to clone the served repo, move the served repo to some other place, `git init --bare` (fix permissions or do it as httpd user) and push again.

---

[problem-with-git-remote-refs-heads-master-is-not-an-ancestor-of-local-refs-h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098894/problem-with-git-remote-refs-heads-master-is-not-an-ancestor-of-local-refs-h) is a question on Stackoverflow about the same error message on a similar setup.